# Tesnorflow custom layer that loops over ragged tensor cannot be built

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, layer, ragged

I am trying customize a layer in tensorflow. The layer has to take ragged tesnor with unidentified length as input. But the code is stuck when trying to build the layer. Even the simple code attached below could not work properly.

```
import tensorflow as tf
class myLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myLayer, self).__init__()
        self._supports_ragged_inputs = True


    def call(self, inputs):
        # Try to loop over ragged tensor
        for x in inputs:
            pass
        return tf.constant(0)

# Input is ragged tensor
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 1), ragged=True)

layer1 = myLayer()
output = layer1(inputs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran your code in `Tensorflow version 2.2.0`, I got the below error in the `for` loop -

**Error -**

```
ValueError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-24-1681d59017fc>:10 call  *
        for x in inputs:
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py:359 for_stmt
        iter_, extra_test, body, get_state, set_state, symbol_names, opts)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py:491 _tf_ragged_for_stmt
        opts)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py:885 _tf_while_stmt
        aug_test, aug_body, init_vars, **opts)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py:2688 while_loop
        back_prop=back_prop)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/while_v2.py:104 while_loop
        maximum_iterations)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/while_v2.py:1258 _build_maximum_iterations_loop_var
        maximum_iterations, dtype=dtypes.int32, name="maximum_iterations")
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1317 convert_to_tensor
        (dtype.name, value.dtype.name, value))

    ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype int64: <tf.Tensor 'my_layer_15/strided_slice:0' shape=() dtype=int64>
```

So I just performed the below experiment to understand the data type produced by the `for` loop and `enumerate` when using `inputs`. `for` loop generates a `tensor` class whereas `enumerate` generates a `int` class.

**Experiment Code -**

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 1), ragged=True)

for x in inputs:
  print(type(x))
  break

for i,x in enumerate(inputs):
  print(type(i))
  break
```

**Output -**

```
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
<class 'int'>
```

So I modified your code as below and it worked fine -

**Fixed Code -**

```
import tensorflow as tf
class myLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myLayer, self).__init__()
        self._supports_ragged_inputs = True


    def call(self, inputs):
        # Try to loop over ragged tensor
        # for x in inputs:  # Throws Error
        for i,x in enumerate(inputs): #Enumerate Works fine
          break                       #Using break as pass will go into loop 
        return tf.constant(0)

# Input is ragged tensor
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 1), ragged=True)

layer1 = myLayer()
output = layer1(inputs)
print(output)
```

**Output -**

```
Tensor("my_layer_17/Identity:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @Jing - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.